# How to read and write multiple files?

Tags: python

I want to write a program for this: In a folder I have *n* number of files; first read one file and perform some operation then store result in a separate file. Then read 2nd file, perform operation again and save result in new 2nd file. Do the same procedure for *n* number of files. The program reads all files one by one and stores results of each file separately. Please give examples how I can do it.

Comment: Probably. But at the same time, I'm just learning Python myself, seems like a good excercise to remind myself I'm not banging my head against a wall. If he doesn't care enough to learn this level stuff himself, then who am I to argue? At the end of the day, if you fail an exam, you've still failed.

Comment: I tagged it as homework; asking and answering homework questions are in the site's roster, however for the asker's benefit I would like that we ask them first to provide code that doesn't work so far.

Answer (score 18):

I think what you miss is how to retrieve all the files in that directory.
To do so, use the glob module.
Here is an example which will duplicate all the files with extension *.txt to files with extension *.out

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt')           # create the list of file
for file_name in list_of_files:
  FI = open(file_name, 'r')
  FO = open(file_name.replace('txt', 'out'), 'w') 
  for line in FI:
    FO.write(line)

  FI.close()
  FO.close()
```

Comment: One small issue with this example. What happens if I have a file called 'mytxtfile.txt'?

Answer (score 13):

```
import sys

# argv is your commandline arguments, argv[0] is your program name, so skip it
for n in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(n) #print out the filename we are currently processing
    input = open(n, "r")
    output = open(n + ".out", "w")
    # do some processing
    input.close()
    output.close()
```

Then call it like:

```
./foo.py bar.txt baz.txt
```

Comment: print(n) to make it python 3 compatible. Still works with 2.4 at least, as well.

Comment: it may be overkill for a single argument, but I'd recommend the optparse module for command line parsing.  Takes care of ugly tasks like handling quotes, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You may find the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module useful.  It is designed for exactly this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've just learned of the os.walk() command recently, and it may help you here.
It allows you to walk down a directory tree structure.

```
import os
OUTPUT_DIR = 'C:\\RESULTS'
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        read_f = open(os.join(path,file),'r')
        write_f = open(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR,file))

        # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Combined answer incorporating directory or specific list of filenames arguments:

```
import sys
import os.path
import glob

def processFile(filename):
    fileHandle = open(filename, "r")
    for line in fileHandle:
        # do some processing
        pass
    fileHandle.close()

def outputResults(filename):
    output_filemask = "out"
    fileHandle = open("%s.%s" % (filename, output_filemask), "w")
    # do some processing
    fileHandle.write('processed\n')
    fileHandle.close()

def processFiles(args):
    input_filemask = "log"
    directory = args[1]
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        print "processing a directory"
        list_of_files = glob.glob('%s/*.%s' % (directory, input_filemask))
    else:
        print "processing a list of files"
        list_of_files = sys.argv[1:]

    for file_name in list_of_files:
        print file_name
        processFile(file_name)
        outputResults(file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
        processFiles(sys.argv)
    else:
        print 'usage message'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pylab import * 
import csv 
import os 
import glob 
import re 
x=[] 
y=[]

f=open("one.txt",'w')

for infile in glob.glob(('*.csv')):
    #   print "" +infile
    csv23=csv2rec(""+infile,'rb',delimiter=',')
    for line in csv23:      
        x.append(line[1])
        #  print len(x)
    for i in range(3000,8000):
        y.append(x[i])
    print ""+infile,"\t",mean(y)
    print >>f,""+infile,"\t\t",mean(y)
    del y[:len(y)]
    del x[:len(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing also works for reading multiple files, my file name is `fedaralist_1.txt` and `federalist_2.txt` and like this, I have 84 files till `fedaralist_84.txt`

And I'm reading the files as f.

```py
for file in filename:
        with open(f'federalist_{file}.txt','r') as f:
             f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I saw this double `with open()` somewhere but couldn't remember where. So I built a small example in case someone needs.

```
""" A module to clean code(js, py, json or whatever) files saved as .txt files to 
be used in HTML code blocks.  """
from os import listdir
from os.path import abspath, dirname, splitext
from re import sub, MULTILINE

def cleanForHTML():
    """ This function will search a directory text files to be edited. """

    ## define some regex for our search and replace. We are looking for <, > and &
    ## To replaced with &ls;, &gt; and &amp;. We might want to replace proper whitespace
    ## chars to as well? (r'\t', '    ') and (f'\n', '<br>')
    search_ = ((r'(<)', '&lt;'), (r'(>)', '&gt;'), (r'(&)', '&amp;'))

    ## Read  and loop our file location. Our location is the same one that our python file is in.
    for loc in listdir(abspath(dirname(__file__))):

        ## Here we split our filename into it's parts ('fileName', '.txt')
        name = splitext(loc)

        if name[1] == '.txt':
            ## we found our .txt file so we can start file operations.
            with open(loc, 'r') as file_1, open(f'{name[0]}(fixed){name[1]}', 'w') as file_2:

                ## read our first file
                retFile = file_1.read()

                ## find and replace some text.
                for find_ in search_:
                    retFile = sub(find_[0], find_[1], retFile, 0, MULTILINE)

                ## finally we can write to our newly created text file.
                file_2.write(retFile)
```